# merge tags - datasynchronization and data-synchronization

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, retag-request, synonym-request

[datasynchronization](/questions/tagged/datasynchronization) should become a synonym of [data-synchronization](/questions/tagged/data-synchronization) - the former has a useful tag wiki page, so if that can be transferred to the latter's wiki that would be great.

The [data-synchronization](/questions/tagged/data-synchronization) version seems more readable since there are two words here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds reasonable.

I merged [datasynchronization](/questions/tagged/datasynchronization) into [data-synchronization](/questions/tagged/data-synchronization) and set up a synonym.

Comment: How about the "sync" and "synchronization" tags? It appears that they haven't been merged yet.